# По какой-то причине моя while True функция перестает работать

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Мой код дает реквесты на roblox.com/groups/, после 49-50 реквестов, код перестает работать. В консоли кроме `200` ничего не дает. Не ошибки, ничего. Оно просто останавливается. Что делать? Может я сделал что-то не так?

```
async def robloxGroupFunction():
    global groupsCount

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        fileCount = 0
        while True:
            groupId = random.randint(3333, 33333333)
            async with session.get(f"https://www.roblox.com/groups/{groupId}/a#!/about") as request:
                print(request.status)
                if request.ok:
                    match = re.search(r'<meta name="description" content="(.*)" />', await request.text())

                    if match:
                        if "owned by" in match.group(1): pass
                        elif "Roblox is a global platform" in match.group(1): pass
                        else:
                            groupsCount += 1
                            await bot.get_channel(1170166038508359700).send(f"https://www.roblox.com/groups/{groupId}/- **:warning: THIS MESSAGE IS ONLY FOR DEVELOPING PURPOSES. DO NOT OPEN IT OR INTERACT WITH IT.**")
                else:
                    print('not ok')

            await asyncio.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: Я все же нашел возможную причину, мне в консоли выдает Timeout. Щас попробую сделать проверку, а далее может быть вопрос уже будет решен.

Answer (score 0):

все-же сам нашел решение вопроса.

Как оказывается, после определенного времени выдается ошибка `Timeout`. Добавив простой `try:` и `except:` все решило. Вот измененный код:

```py
async def robloxGroupFunction():
    global groupsCount

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.001)
        while True:
            ...
        except:
            pass
```

Надеюсь это поможет, если кто столкнется с такой же проблемой.